# Superscript text in HTML <input type="submit" />

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use superscript text in the value field of the `<input>` tag (for example to use with registration mark)?

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sometext&reg;"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use the [`<button type="submit">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button) element instead of `<input type="submit">` Then you can include any markup you want in the description, like, e.g., [`<sup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/sup) for superscripted text:

```
<button type="submit">someText with <sup>superscripted parts</sup> </button>
```

Comment: Note that this will cause problems in oldish-IE if you have multiple submit buttons that you want to distinguish between on the server. If that isn't the case, this is the best approach to the problem.

Comment: Let's say I am not able to use <button> element. Any other solution?

Comment: @tomexx You could resemble the same behavior using a `<div>` with the same contents and styling. Then you would have to attach a JavaScript click handler to that `<div>` to trigger the form submission.

Answer (score 2):

Or with CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/jxmaA/

HTML

```
<button class="tradeMark" type="submit">someText with</button>
```

CSS

```
.tradeMark:after{
  content: ' ©';
  font-size:xx-small;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

EDIT: this solution too won't work with `<input type="submit"/>` , cause :after and :before are not applied...

Answer (score 1):

If you must use `<input type=submit>` and not `<button type=submit>`, you are out of luck. The text must be specified in the `value` attribute, which is taken as plain text. You could use superscript *characters* like “²” there, but there is more superscript version of “®” as a character – but its appearance varies greatly across fonts, being much more superscript in some fonts than e.g. in Arial.

So the practical move might be to specify a different font for the button. For consistency, you would then probably want to use that same font for all submit button texts, e.g.

```
input[type=submit] { font-family: Calibri; }
```

Usual CSS Caveats apply. In particular, it can be difficult to specify a good list of font families in this context. (Calibri is great, but its availability is far from universal.)