# Superscript in input field of text type

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML input field like this:

```
<input id="op" type="text" value="0" />
```

I want to update the value of this field dynamically with some string containing superscript. It did not work and I tried this.

```
document.getElementById("op").value="a<sup>3</sup>" //don't work
document.getElementById("op").innerHTML="a<sup>3</sup>" //don't work
```

How can I get this to work? I could have tried to figure the rest myself but since I am already forced to ask this, I would like to tell what I am planning to do.

```
 var x=3; var y=2;
 document.getElementById("op").innerHTML="a<sup> x-y </sup>";
```

Comment: You can't do that in an `input` tag. You'll have to come up with a sophisticated textbox for yourself.

Comment: Also, `<input>` tags are self-closing. You don't need a closing tag.

Comment: @mohkhan : All my worst fears comes true...Thanks

Comment: @Blender, ...but you may

Comment: ["Permitted content None, this is a void element."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input).

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/10841480/2420583

Comment: Have you considered using a WYSIWYG? Only way to input HTML tags into the value.

Comment: There's always content editable div's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about a plugin:

```
$.fn.superScript = function() {
    var chars = '+−=()0123456789AaÆᴂɐɑɒBbcɕDdðEeƎəɛɜɜfGgɡɣhHɦIiɪɨᵻɩjJʝɟKklLʟᶅɭMmɱNnɴɲɳŋOoɔᴖᴗɵȢPpɸrRɹɻʁsʂʃTtƫUuᴜᴝʉɥɯɰʊvVʋʌwWxyzʐʑʒꝯᴥβγδθφχнნʕⵡ',
        sup   = '⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ᴬᵃᴭᵆᵄᵅᶛᴮᵇᶜᶝᴰᵈᶞᴱᵉᴲᵊᵋᶟᵌᶠᴳᵍᶢˠʰᴴʱᴵⁱᶦᶤᶧᶥʲᴶᶨᶡᴷᵏˡᴸᶫᶪᶩᴹᵐᶬᴺⁿᶰᶮᶯᵑᴼᵒᵓᵔᵕᶱᴽᴾᵖᶲʳᴿʴʵʶˢᶳᶴᵀᵗᶵᵁᵘᶸᵙᶶᶣᵚᶭᶷᵛⱽᶹᶺʷᵂˣʸᶻᶼᶽᶾꝰᵜᵝᵞᵟᶿᵠᵡᵸჼˤⵯ';

    return this.each(function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/<sup[^>]*>(.*?)<\/sup>/g, function(x) {
            var str = '',
                txt = $.trim($(x).unwrap().text());

            for (var i=0; i<txt.length; i++) {
                var n = chars.indexOf(txt[i]);
                str += (n!=-1 ? sup[n] : txt[i]);
            }
            return str;
        });
    });
}
```

called like:

```
$('input').superScript();
```

Could probably be bound to keyup etc as well, and rather easily converted to plain javascript and not jQuery, but I just made it, so if it works, modify it to suit your needs ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/E5Wkv/2/)

Comment: +1 Awesome.  One doubt how did you add `sup   = '⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ᴬᵃᴭᵆᵄᵅᶛᴮᵇᶜᶝᴰᵈᶞᴱᵉᴲᵊᵋᶟᵌᶠᴳᵍᶢˠʰᴴʱᴵⁱᶦᶤᶧᶥʲᴶᶨᶡᴷᵏˡᴸᶫᶪᶩᴹᵐᶬᴺⁿᶰᶮᶯᵑᴼᵒᵓᵔᵕᶱ` in your html code, means how browser renders this.

Comment: It's all UFT-8, so shouldn't be an issue, it has to be the actual characters, not entities or anything else, as that won't work in a value attribute.

Comment: it works with value attribute.  http://jsfiddle.net/zuE7k/ so he can have directly if his page is encoded with UTF8.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yup, it works with anything, it just replaces the characters with the equivalent superscript character.

Comment: I agree, very helpful.  I've taken your work and extended it to include subscripted numbers as well, something I will need in a tool I'm writing.  It's at http://jsfiddle.net/pb2au/4hUAd/

Answer (score 3):

`<input>` is not a container, and so does not 'contain' any html.

The value attribute of `<input>` must be plain text, so no you can't do what I believe you're attempting.

There are workarounds however, of varying usefulness, depending on what you really need to do. See [Superscript text in HTML <input type="submit" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252826/superscript-text-in-html-input-type-submit)

Further, you might also find the use of 'editable' content in a `<div>` to be of value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable