# Add <sup> in PHP not working

Tags: php, html

I am editing a wordpress page and I am required to put square meter simbol m<sup>2</sup> into a textbox. However I've been at it for an hour or more and I cannot get it to work. Php errors range from syntax error to `T_ENCLOSED_STRING`.

The `Min Area (m2)` is the text I want to edit.

The code:

```
<input type="text" class="field" name="area-min" id="area-min" 
       placeholder="<?php _e('Min Area (in m2)','realspace'); ?>" 
       value="<?php echo $_GET['area-min']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Does the `m<sup>2</sup>` have to be language supported or can you move it out of the `_e()` call?

Comment: You're saying `_e('Min Area (in m<sup>2</sup>)','real space');` gives you PHP syntax errors...?!

Comment: Do <sup> tags even work in an HTML placeholder?

Comment: Perhaps you should use the Unicode "㎡" character.

Comment: Could you not generate a variable of the string in php then echo it out in the placeholder ?

Comment: 'Min Area (m<sup>2</sup>)' prints it out like its written. Putting it like 'Min Area (m".<sup>2</sup>.")' gives me errors.

Comment: May help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114201/html-inside-or-e-language-translation-string

Comment: The `_e()` function probably escapes the output so it's html safe. That is why `<sup>2</sup>` gets displayed and you do not get the html tags.

Comment: @Arjan I think so too, because it works if I just echo the <sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put HTML tag in inputs. But, you can use superscript characters:

```
<input type="text" class="field" name="area-min" id="area-min" 
       placeholder="Min Area (in m²)" 
       value="<?php echo $_GET['area-min']; ?>" />
```

Here, I'm using the `²` character.

See also: [Superscript in input field of text type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683654/superscript-in-input-field-of-text-type)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the HTML superscript-2 character is  [`&#178;`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b2/index.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to change to UTF-8 when trying to copy the ² symbol. It didn't work under the ANSI.

Answer (score 6):

You can't put HTML in a placeholder. What you want is the special character ² which is `&sup2;`

e.g.

`_e('Min Area (in M&sup2;)','realspace')`