# How to use superscript in an html text input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a simple input tag (which I prettify using Bootstrap) in which I now want to place a superscript (to display "m<sup>2</sup>"). The problem is that when I do this:

```
<input class="form-control" name="gla" placeholder="m<sup>2</sup>" type="text">
```

the placeholder literally shows this: `m<sup>2</sup>`

Does anybody know how I can properly display the superscript? All tips are welcome!

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683654/superscript-in-input-field-of-text-type

Comment: Both Rhumborl and Lekhnath have correct answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use the UTF-8 character for superscripted ². Also be sure to set the charset of the document to `UTF-8`.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="form-control" name="gla" placeholder="m²" type="text" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17684181/1212463) might be of help.

Comment: The character “²” works just fine as such using *any* encoding that has a code for it, including e.g. ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252.

Comment: I tested it on my desktop with charsets Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1, but the output of the placeholder was "mÂ²", so you HAVE to change the charset to UTF-8, or Firefox and Ubuntu are doing something wrong.

Comment: You get wrong results if the *actual* encoding is not the same as the *declared* encoding. This also applies if one of them is UTF-8.

Comment: Yes true, I saved the document as UTF-8, that's why I got these results. My bad.

Answer (score 8):

How about using HTML Entities

```
<input class="form-control" name="gla" placeholder="m&sup2;" type="text">
```

[Yes it works](http://jsfiddle.net/lekhnath/jvx89kuk/)

Comment: Although it works in your fiddle it somehow doesn't work in my code. Maybe it has something to do with bootstrap or one of the (too many) js libraries I load?

Comment: Hmmm, very weird that it doesn't work in my code, I have no idea why. But in the end the use of the UTF-8 character as suggested by lmazgon works, so I'm going to use that. Thanks a million for your time and effort though!

Comment: No problem, it may be useful for some other who are willing to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to insert the ² character directly into the html tag - it is ascii code 262/ octal 178. This should render safely as it is just ASCII, not Unicode.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="m²" />
```

Comment: You can indeed use “²” as such. But entity codes do work in attribute values. And the character “²” is not an ASCII character. And all characters you use are Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

Within an attribute value, you can use characters just like in document content (except for the quote character used as attribute value delimiter). This means that you can write the superscript two character as such, or using a named character reference, or a numeric reference. When using the character as such, you need to make sure that the character encoding is properly declared (corresponds to the actual encoding).

```html
<input class="form-control" name="gla" placeholder="m²" type="text"><br>
<input class="form-control" name="gla" placeholder="m&sup2;" type="text"><br>
<input class="form-control" name="gla" placeholder="m&#178;" type="text"><br>
<input class="form-control" name="gla" placeholder="m&#xb2;" type="text"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You can use,

HTML Entity (Named)     `&sup2;`

HTML Entity (Decimal)   `&#178;`

HTML Entity (Hexadecimal)   `&#x00B2;`

```
 <input class="form-control" name="gla"  placeholder="m&#178;" type="text">
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/q8310f27/1/