# Superscripts and subscripts in HTML input

Tags: javascript

I am making a small JavaScript web app that deals with chemical formulas, so I need to allow users to input superscripts. The easiest thing for users would be having the text editor switch to superscript when they press ^. How can I do this with an HTML textarea?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Try and provide some code examples of what you have tried, people are more willing and better able to help you

Comment: You can’t. You can only format the whole textarea content as one. `contentEditable` is something you might want to look into.

Comment: You could have a div that *renders* the entered formula showing the superscripts in response to changes in the textarea, but keep the textarea itself as plain text. Presumably you need subscripts anyway for chemical formulae.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend leveraging an existing solution. Take a look at [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/).

Regarding creating your own such system from scratch, there is no simple solution. You would need to do independent research and experimentation and return to Stack Overflow with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from the function in [adeneo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683654/superscript-in-input-field-of-text-type?answertab=votes#tab-top)

---

Check this fiddle here : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/p6z2u6hj/)

---

Usage : To type a superscript , press ^ --> type in the superscript --> press Esc , the superscript will then appear in the textarea.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var temp = {}; // store keypresses here
  var current_value = "";
  $("#text_area").keydown(function(e) {
    temp[e.which] = true;
  });
  $('#text_area').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27 && current_value != "") {
      var length_1 = current_value.length;
      var length_without_sup = length_1 - 5;
      var substr_superstring = $('#text_area').val().substr(length_without_sup);
      var current_text_2 = current_value + substr_superstring;
      current_text_2 = current_text_2 + "</sup>";
      $('#text_area').val(current_text_2);
      $('#text_area').superScript();
    }
    var flag_shift = false;
    var flag_super = false;
    for (var key in temp) {
      if (key == 16) {
        flag_shift = true;
      } else if (key == 54) {
        flag_super = true;
      }
    }
    if (flag_shift == true && flag_super == true) {
      var current_text = $('#text_area').val();
      current_text_2 = current_text.substr(0, current_text.length - 1);
      current_text_2 = current_text_2 + "<sup>";
      $('#text_area').val(current_text_2);
      current_value = hide_superscript_tag();
    }
    delete temp[e.which];
  });
});

function hide_superscript_tag() {
  var current_value = $('#text_area').val();
  current_value_2 = current_value.substr(0, current_value.length - 5);
  $('#text_area').val(current_value_2);
  return current_value;
}
$.fn.superScript = function() {
  var chars = '+−=()0123456789AaÆᴂɐɑɒBbcɕDdðEeƎəɛɜɜfGgɡɣhHɦIiɪɨᵻɩjJʝɟKklLʟᶅɭMmɱNnɴɲɳŋOoɔᴖᴗɵȢPpɸqrRɹɻʁsʂʃTtƫUuᴜᴝʉɥɯɰʊvVʋʌwWxyzʐʑʒꝯᴥβγδθφχнნʕⵡ',
    sup = '⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ᴬᵃᴭᵆᵄᵅᶛᴮᵇᶜᶝᴰᵈᶞᴱᵉᴲᵊᵋᶟᵌᶠᴳᵍᶢˠʰᴴʱᴵⁱᶦᶤᶧᶥʲᴶᶨᶡᴷᵏˡᴸᶫᶪᶩᴹᵐᶬᴺⁿᶰᶮᶯᵑᴼᵒᵓᵔᵕᶱᴽᴾᵖᶲqʳᴿʴʵʶˢᶳᶴᵀᵗᶵᵁᵘᶸᵙᶶᶣᵚᶭᶷᵛⱽᶹᶺʷᵂˣʸᶻᶼᶽᶾꝰᵜᵝᵞᵟᶿᵠᵡᵸჼˤⵯ';

  return this.each(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/<sup[^>]*>(.*?)<\/sup>/g, function(x) {
      var str = '',
        txt = $.trim($(x).unwrap().text());

      for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
        var n = chars.indexOf(txt[i]);
        str += (n != -1 ? sup[n] : txt[i]);
      }
      return str;
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text_area">
</textarea>
```